# Does converting an integer to ulong cost much time?

Tags: c#

Example:

```
ulong a = // some value
if(a == 0)
  // do something
```

When executing the test if `a == 0` the value 0 has to be converted from its default value to ulong. Does this converting cost much time?

Would it take less time when testing `a == 0UL` instead?

I am working on a time critical project, so every operation less is good.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, you should be profiling your code.

Comment: By the way, seriously, why don't you just profile it?

Comment: Why not just write (a == 0UL) if you're worried?

Comment: It's likely that the compiler converted that `0` to a `ulong` so that at runtime there is no conversion. That said, the cost of converting from `int` to `ulong` at runtime is essentially zero. It's a single instruction that executes very quickly. If this is where you're concentrating your optimization efforts, then either your program is already as fast as it can be, or you haven't profiled it to determine where the real bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long story short, there is no run-time impact of comparison to constant values of smaller bit widths.

And here's the long story:

When you compare to a constant the compiler will widen the constant at compile time, so there will be no run-time impact.  You don't have to explicitly specify the constant size, since the compiler is smart enough to figure out the right size to use.  Same goes with comparing a `double` to a floating-point constant.

When you're comparing to a variable the compiler generates code to widen the value at run-time.  Depending on the types and platforms involved (64-bit type on 32-bit platform for instance) this could consume a few cycles.  Generally though the operation is fairly quick.

For example, loading a signed 32-bit integer variable from the stack into an unsigned 64-bit register is a single instruction on x64 platforms:

```
movsx rax, dword ptr[rsp+<offset>]
```

On x86 platforms it takes a few more operations to load and sign-extend the value through two 32-bit registers and a bit of juggling... no surprises there.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference. They're the exact same operation (obviously the same results in all cases) and any compiler too dumb to realize that would not be a compiler any sane person would use.

Comment: I'd love to see that claim backed up with the produced bytecode.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If the produced bytecode was bad, that would just prove that whatever produced it is bad. It is immediately obvious that the operations are precisely equivalent. Any compiler that didn't know that would be so horribly broken trying to optimize for it would be a fool's errand. Even low-end compilers routinely recognize equivalences [far more complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler#Specific_techniques) than this. Any compiler that couldn't do this would at best be considered a toy.

Comment: We're talking about the standard Microsoft C# compiler (or Roslyn if you're feeling really ambitious), and Mono - these are the only actually used compilers for C# afaik and OP is most likely talking about the standard MS C# compiler - what happens _in practice_ .

Comment: Do you see people complaining those compilers are horribly broken or toys? If not, then that must mean they are sane. In any event, if the compilers were this horribly broken, it would just mean you *couldn't* really optimize for them at all. Trying to optimize to their fundamental brokenness would be doomed to fail for many reasons.

Comment: The folding/propagation of constants is a basic non-destructive optimization that any compiler does (even with disabled optimizations). Since 0 would need to be cast to 0L, the compiler should automatically do it. Anyway, the cost of converting uint to ulong is virtually zero, since it just consists in setting to 0 and not ignoring the 32 most significant bits of the corresponding register. Unless the compiler is so smart it can use 64 bit registers to store two 32 bit values, but then it should also be smart enough to optimize that code.